# Hibernate places null instead of empty collection

Tags: java, hibernate

I have the following query:

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT c."data"->'property_data'->>'name' AS propertyName
    FROM contract.contract c LEFT JOIN other_property_owner opo ON c.contract_id = opo.c_id 
    WHERE c.organization_id = :orgId AND c.sublease_type = 'MAIN_CONTRACT'
    AND (:ownerIds IS NULL OR c.main_property_owner_id IN (:ownerIds) OR opo.po_id IN (:ownerIds))
    AND (:contractKey IS NULL OR c."key" = CAST(:contractKey as TEXT))
    AND (:propertyName IS NULL OR c."data"->'property_data'->>'name' ILIKE CONCAT('%', :propertyName ,'%'))
    AND (:tenantName IS NULL OR c."data"->'main_tenant_details'->>'full_name' = CAST(:tenantName AS TEXT))
```

When ownerIds argument is null for some reason hibernate throws an error:

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist: bigint = bytea
  Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
  Position: 283
```

and the query in the logs looks like that:

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT c."data"->'property_data'->>'name' AS propertyName
    FROM contract.contract c LEFT JOIN other_property_owner opo ON c.contract_id = opo.c_id
    WHERE c.organization_id = ? AND c.sublease_type = 'MAIN_CONTRACT'
    AND (? IS NULL OR c.main_property_owner_id IN (?) OR opo.po_id IN (?))
    AND (? IS NULL OR c."key" = CAST(? as TEXT))
    AND (? IS NULL OR c."data"->'property_data'->>'name' ILIKE CONCAT('%', ? ,'%'))
    AND (? IS NULL OR c."data"->'main_tenant_details'->>'full_name' = CAST(? AS TEXT))
```

As you can see Hibernate for some reason placed question mark instead of null.
However when I pass an empty collection instead of ownerIds, I see the following in the logs:

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT c."data"->'property_data'->>'name' AS propertyName
    FROM contract.contract c LEFT JOIN other_property_owner opo ON c.contract_id = opo.c_id
    WHERE c.organization_id = ? AND c.sublease_type = 'MAIN_CONTRACT'
    AND (null IS NULL OR c.main_property_owner_id IN (null) OR opo.po_id IN (null))
    AND (? IS NULL OR c."key" = CAST(? as TEXT))
    AND (? IS NULL OR c."data"->'property_data'->>'name' ILIKE CONCAT('%', ? ,'%'))
    AND (? IS NULL OR c."data"->'main_tenant_details'->>'full_name' = CAST(? AS TEXT))
```

As you can see Hibernate substituted null instead of ownerIds variable.

I wander what causes such behaviour? And why when null is passed the first clause `(:ownerIds is null)` doesn't work and Hibernate throws an operator does not exist error?

Answer (score 0):

When passing null for a parameter, Hibernate usually relies on inference in HQL to determine the type of the parameter. Since this is a native query though, Hibernate does not know the type of the parameter and in 5.6 by default chooses to bind such nulls with `PreparedStatement#setBytes`. The JDBC driver then assumes that this is of the type `bytea` and a predicate like `opo.po_id IN (?)` essentially is `opo.po_id = ?` which will compare a `bigint` against a `bytea` in case you bind null.

In your particular case, the only way you can make this work is by specifying the type during parameter binding. You can do that through the `org.hibernate.query.Query` API which allows you to specify an optional third argument in `setParameter`/`setParameterList`, which represents the type of the value. Use `StandardBasicTypes.LONG` as argument and the query should work as intended.